# How to get <tr> count in HTML table - using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Datatables to achieve search and sort functionality on HTML table `<table>`.

I have more then 100 rows in `<table>` and I used `iDisplayLength=6` attribute to display on 6 records at the same time and enabled paging functionality for more records.

The problem is: I want to count that how many `<tr>` in `<table>` using jquery.

I used follwing code for that but it gives count 6 `<tr>` always because I used `DisplayLength=6`.
But I want actual count of `<tr>`

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_grdRX").dataTable({
         "iDisplayLength": 6,
         "bLengthChange": false,
         "bFilter": true,
         "bInfo": false,
         "bAutoWidth": false 
     });
 });

function getCount() {
    alert($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_grdRX tr').length);
}
```

How can I get a count of all the rows?

Comment: care to show some working fiddle for us to fiddle with

Comment: Do you mean the total count of all rows, not just the rows currently displayed?

Comment: @markpsmith - Yes exactly. I want total count of all rows which is more then 100+

Comment: Are you using server-side data? If so, you can use `iTotalDisplayRecords`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like DataTables is removing the rows that aren't on the current page from the DOM, so you aren't going to be able to count them with a jQuery selector. You'll have to use the DataTables API, specifically the fnGetHiddenNodes function:

```
var table = $('##ContentPlaceHolder1_grdRX').dataTable();
             $('#button').click( function () {
             var hidden = table.fnGetHiddenNodes();
             alert( hidden.length +' nodes were returned' ); } );
```

Comment: Not working... what is **fnGetHiddenNodes()** ?? is this any built in function for jquery datatables?

Comment: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/#fnGetHiddenNodes please go through It may be helpfull for you. Thanks